# NSMutableArray assignment and updates using mutableArrayValueForKey result in inconsistent results

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

**NOTE: Question has been re-worded for clarity and updated with new information**

I've encountered an issue when using `mutableArrayValueForKey` in conjunction with an object's property that is assigned to a variable in a 2nd object.

My model object contains multiple `NSMutableArray` properties.

```
@interface LBYCardDeck : NSObject
@property(strong,nonatomic,readonly)NSMutableArray *removedCardDeck;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *discardDeck;
```

My view object contains an assignment of a particular `NSMutableArray` to a variable based on an enumerated type.

```
@implementation LBYCardDeckView
{
    NSMutableArray* cardArray;
}

-(void)setDeckType:(LBYDeckType)deckType
{
    _deckType = deckType;
    switch (_deckType) {
        case LBYDTDiscards:
            cardArray = cardDeck.discardDeck;
            break;
        case LBYDTRemoved:
            cardArray = cardDeck.removedCardDeck;
            break;
        default:
            NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid Deck Type");
        break;
    }
}
```

I get two different results based on whether the property in the model is declared `readonly` or not. If the property is declared `readonly` everything works as expected. If the property is not declared `readonly` the behavior is the same as if a `copy` was used during assignment: not all the elements in the array are reflected in the assigned variable after subsequent updates occur.

I have since fixed the issue by changing the variable in the view object to a property.

```
@property(weak,nonatomic,readonly)NSMutableArray *cardArray;
```

I am curious as to what is happening here. Why did the assignment to a variable not work as expected?

UPDATE:

I narrowed down the problem to the `mutableArrayValueForKey` method that I'm using for KVO purposes.

Below is a sample program that demonstrates there is unexpected behavior (bug?) occurring that seems to indicate a copy is being performed in the background. Changing the property `readonly` yields different results

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *mutableArray2;
```

versus:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic,readonly)NSMutableArray *mutableArray2;
```

Object1 .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Object1 : NSObject

@property(strong,nonatomic,readonly)NSMutableArray *mutableArray1;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *mutableArray2;

-(void)array1Update:(id)obj;
-(void)array2Update:(id)obj;
@end
```

Object1 .m

```
#import "Object1.h"

@implementation Object1

-(id)init {
 self = [super init];
 _mutableArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 _mutableArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 return  self;
}
-(void)array1Update:(id)obj {
[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(mutableArray1))] addObject:obj];
}

-(void)array2Update:(id)obj {
[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(mutableArray2))] addObject:obj];
}
@end
```

Object2 .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Object2 : NSObject
-(void)assignMyArray:(NSMutableArray*)obj1MutableArray;
-(void)logContents;
@end
```

Object2 .m

```
#import "Object2.h"
@implementation Object2{
    NSMutableArray*myArray;
}
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    return  self;
}
-(void)assignMyArray:(NSMutableArray*)obj1MutableArray{
    myArray = obj1MutableArray;
}
-(void)logContents{
    NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
}
@end
```

ViewController .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Object1.h"
#import "Object2.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
{
Object1* obj1;
Object2* obj2Array1;
Object2* obj2Array2;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
obj1 =[[Object1 alloc]init];
//add some data
[obj1 array1Update:@"1A"];
[obj1 array1Update:@"1B"];
[obj1 array2Update:@"2A"];
[obj1 array2Update:@"2B"];

//assign array 1 to obj2Array1
obj2Array1 =[[Object2 alloc]init];
[obj2Array1 assignMyArray:obj1.mutableArray1];

//assign array 2 to obj2Array2
obj2Array2 =[[Object2 alloc]init];
[obj2Array2 assignMyArray:obj1.mutableArray2];

//check values
[obj2Array1 logContents];
[obj2Array2 logContents];

//add some more data
[obj1 array1Update:@"1C"];
[obj1 array1Update:@"1D"];
[obj1 array2Update:@"2C"];
[obj1 array2Update:@"2D"];

//check values
[obj2Array1 logContents];
[obj2Array2 logContents];
}
@end
```

Comment: When you copy an object, you copy the object.  If you have a property that does not do `copy` then you just copy the pointer.

Comment: I think you're confused. Post the assignment to your mutable data model property that you think is resulting in a copy.

Comment: Hot Licks: I know that. It appears a copy was performed behind the scenes even though no specific copy was invoked.

Comment: Duncan C : The code IS posted. It's performed in the setDeckType switch

Comment: Do you have a custom _getter_ for the property?

Comment: Josh: No custom getter.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't result in the behavior you've described. Please post [an example that does](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Stupid question:  Why did you add a new property to the model if you knew it would contain the same pointer as an existing property?

Comment: Hot Licks: It doesn't. There are several "card decks" in the model and the view object will be updated based on the one assigned to it by the enumerated card deck type.

Comment: Josh: see updated code above.

Comment: You have yet to tell us what assignment statement is supposedly doing this, how the value used in the assignment is developed, how the assigned-to location is declared, and how you're detecting this "problem".  In fact, hardly any of the info required of a valid question is present.

Comment: Hot Licks:  It's all in the code:   NSMutableArray* cardArray; cardArray = cardDeck.discardDeck; I'm detecting the problem because an index was out of bounds and tracked it down with the NSLog statement (see last code sample) and using the debugger. When the property is not readonly, cardArray has whatever was in it at assignment time. It looks like it's doing a stealth copy.

Comment: You've debugged it improperly.  The only "stealth copy" that occurs is when you assign an object pointer to a property with the `copy` keyword in its definition.

Comment: I just created a test program to prove what's happening. I will edit the above with the sample code. I narrowed it down to this statement :[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(discardDeck))] insertObject:card atIndex:0];

Comment: What the heck is this supposed to be:  `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(discardDeck))` ??

Comment: Explain to us what `[[self mutableArrayValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(discardDeck))] insertObject:card atIndex:0];` actually does.

Comment: `mutableArrayValueForKey` is used to update mutable arrays that are the used in Key Value Observing. KVO does not notify when an array is updated by other means. `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(discardDeck))` is used to ensure a selector name is not misspelled. This guarantees you are using an actual selector name. It's a good practice to never type a selector name as a string constant.

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting the example. I see this weird behavior and will look into it when I get a chance tomorrow.